# Runtime Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method when using .PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below VBA script to copy cells. It pastes values in all cells (A to J) but throws runtime error 438 when pasting value in **K**.
I am not sure why is it failing on the last line when it works for the previous lines.

```
Sub Programs()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim i As Long, M As Long
    N = Sheets.Count - 4
    M = 2
    For i = 6 To N
        'copy Form number + Edition date
        Sheets(i).Range("$D$4").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)

        'copy Program
        Sheets(i).Range("$C$180").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("B" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("B" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        'copy ProgramStatus
        Sheets(i).Range("$E$180").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("C" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("C" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)

        'copy Program
        Sheets(i).Range("$C$181").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("D" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("D" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        'copy ProgramStatus
        Sheets(i).Range("$E$181").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("E" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("E" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)

        'copy Program
        Sheets(i).Range("$C$182").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("F" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("F" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        'copy ProgramStatus
        Sheets(i).Range("$E$182").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("G" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("G" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)

        'copy Program
        Sheets(i).Range("$C$183").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("H" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("H" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        'copy ProgramStatus
        Sheets(i).Range("$E$183").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("I" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("I" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)

        'copy Program
        Sheets(i).Range("$C$184").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("J" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("J" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        'copy ProgramStatus
        Sheets(i).Range("$E$184").Copy
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("K" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Programs1").Range("K" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
    M = M + 1
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: You don't need the locked cell references here. Just use `Range("C181")`

Comment: I have removed the $ from range.
I am using a loop and M will increment.
I have tried using xlPasteValues and xlPasteFormats.
Script is still failing

Comment: Remove the `()` around the `xlValues` and `xlFormats`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the Error either, but you can certainly shorten up the code and perhaps isolate why the error is happening. When you have highly redundant code as you do, breaking out that section into a separate method will "functionally isolate" that logic. This is important because if you have an error, you can fix it by changing the logic in just one location. Otherwise you'll have to change all the copy-paste lines that you generated to make the example above. So a routine like this:

```
Private Sub CopyMe(ByVal sheetIndex As Long, _
                   ByVal from As String, _
                   ByVal to As String)
    Sheets(sheetIndex).Range(from).Copy
    With Sheets("Programs1").Range(to)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With
End Sub
```

So now your main logic will look like this:

```
Sub Programs()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim i As Long, M As Long
    N = Sheets.Count - 4
    M = 2
    For i = 6 To N
        CopyMe i, "D4", "A2"      'copy Form number + Edition date
        CopyMe i, "C180", "B2"    'copy Program
        CopyMe i, "E180", "C2"    'copy ProgramStatus
        ' ...
    Next i
End Sub
```

So if, when you structure your code like this, all the `CopyMe` lines work except for column `K`, then you'll know you have a problem with the column, not the same copy-paste lines. (But I think it will work...)

Comment: I used your Private Sub CopyMe() as is and I am getting error "Compile Error Expected Identifier"

Comment: @SAhmed did you try my comment on your code?  You need to remove the `()`.

Comment: I tried something else. Instead of copying each row "Sheets(i).Range("$C$181").Copy", I am copying range of rows "(Sheets(i).Range("C180:E203").Copy)" which has reduced my code as well as not throwing any error message. This will require a little bit of cleanup.